# Debian: Find unknown process pinging ip on old subnet after subnet change

Tags: ip, process

I changed my network subnet from `192.168.1.0` to `10.10.10.0`, but some rogue process is trying to hit port `9100` on `192.168.1.145`

I have tried `sudo lsof -n | grep TCP | grep 9100` with no luck.
I have also tried `sudo netstat -nlpt | grep 192.168.1.145` without luck.
My conclusion is that this isn't working because of the fact that the connection is not being established.

Besides waitig for a complete search for the ip in all files (`sudo grep -Ril -e ´192.168.1.145´ * 2>/dev/null`) to finish, or setting up some sort of dummy nic/ or a `nc` and route to let it connect to, what else can I do to find the process causing this.

I have checked that cups is not installed.

#### Update

It turned out i had misread the IP and it was an old printer installed on a windows machine. uninstalling that fixed it

Comment: port 9100 is usually Prometheus node exporter or HP JetDirect printers

Comment: I'm aware of that. it is the old ip of my printer, which is now `10.10.10.145`

Comment: does this answers your questions: https://serverfault.com/questions/352259/finding-short-lived-tcp-connections-owner-process

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into the question. Post it as an answer instead and accept it when you are allowed to do so. Otherwise the question will stay in the system as unsolved forever.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider  I have rephrased it and posted the solution as an answer. i originally posted it as an update since i didn't see it working,.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer(s) here: https://serverfault.com/a/352275/246640 (tip from the comments)

Running

```sh
while true;do
   ss dst 192.168.1.145 -ntap  '( dport = :9100 )' | grep 145;
   sleep 1; 
done
```

Will make sure to show only a line when a packet is sent to that IP and port...

This diverges from the linked answer in that it shows non-established connections instead of established connections.

#### To verify that it works:

Run this in a different terminal:
`curl 192.168.145:9100` it show up in the output:

```
State                  Recv-Q                Send-Q                               Local Address:Port                                 Peer Address:Port
SYN-SENT               0                     1                                     10.10.10.240:59494                               192.168.1.145:9100                users:(("curl",pid=25945,fd=3))
```